# Play a random sequence of 4 sounds while a video is played in Psychopy?

Tags: python, numpy, random, psychopy

I'm trying to create an experiment using Psychopy.
In the specific I'm trying to create a routine ("trial") where a video ("movie1") is presented and at the same time I would like to play a sequence of 4 sounds (one per second) randomly chosen from a list of 10 in an excel file (sounds.routine.xlsx).
Here's what I have done so far:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division

from psychopy import locale_setup
from psychopy import prefs
from psychopy import sound, gui, visual, core, data, event, logging, clock
from psychopy.constants import (NOT_STARTED, STARTED, PLAYING, PAUSED,
                                STOPPED, FINISHED, PRESSED, RELEASED, FOREVER)

import numpy as np  # whole numpy lib is available, prepend 'np.'
from numpy import (sin, cos, tan, log, log10, pi, average,
                   sqrt, std, deg2rad, rad2deg, linspace, asarray)
from numpy.random import random, randint, normal, shuffle
import os  # handy system and path functions
import sys  # to get file system encoding

from psychopy.hardware import keyboard

# Ensure that relative paths start from the same directory as this script
_thisDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(_thisDir)

# Store info about the experiment session
psychopyVersion = '3.2.4'
expName = 'dsffdsfads'  # from the Builder filename that created this script
expInfo = {'participant': '', 'session': '001'}
dlg = gui.DlgFromDict(dictionary=expInfo, sortKeys=False, title=expName)
if dlg.OK == False:
    core.quit()  # user pressed cancel
expInfo['date'] = data.getDateStr()  # add a simple timestamp
expInfo['expName'] = expName
expInfo['psychopyVersion'] = psychopyVersion

# Data file name stem = absolute path + name; later add .psyexp, .csv, .log, etc
filename = _thisDir + os.sep + u'data/%s_%s_%s' % (expInfo['participant'], expName, expInfo['date'])

# An ExperimentHandler isn't essential but helps with data saving
thisExp = data.ExperimentHandler(name=expName, version='',
    extraInfo=expInfo, runtimeInfo=None,
    originPath='/Users/Documents/dsffdsfads.py',
    savePickle=True, saveWideText=True,
    dataFileName=filename)
# save a log file for detail verbose info
logFile = logging.LogFile(filename+'.log', level=logging.EXP)
logging.console.setLevel(logging.WARNING)  # this outputs to the screen, not a file

endExpNow = False  # flag for 'escape' or other condition => quit the exp
frameTolerance = 0.001  # how close to onset before 'same' frame

# Start Code - component code to be run before the window creation

# Setup the Window
win = visual.Window(
    size=(1024, 768), fullscr=True, screen=0, 
    winType='pyglet', allowGUI=False, allowStencil=False,
    monitor='testMonitor', color=[0,0,0], colorSpace='rgb',
    blendMode='avg', useFBO=True, 
    units='height')
# store frame rate of monitor if we can measure it
expInfo['frameRate'] = win.getActualFrameRate()
if expInfo['frameRate'] != None:
    frameDur = 1.0 / round(expInfo['frameRate'])
else:
    frameDur = 1.0 / 60.0  # could not measure, so guess

# create a default keyboard (e.g. to check for escape)
defaultKeyboard = keyboard.Keyboard()

# Initialize components for Routine "trial"
trialClock = core.Clock()
sound1 = sound.Sound(Sounds, secs=-1, stereo=True, hamming=True,
    name='sound1')
sound1.setVolume(1)
movie1 = visual.MovieStim3(
    win=win, name='movie1',
    noAudio = True,
    filename='Movies/Random_4.mp4',
    ori=0, pos=(0, 0), opacity=1,
    loop=False,
    depth=-1.0,
    )
from np.random import choice

# Create some handy timers
globalClock = core.Clock()  # to track the time since experiment started
routineTimer = core.CountdownTimer()  # to track time remaining of each (non-slip) routine 

# set up handler to look after randomisation of conditions etc
trials = data.TrialHandler(nReps=1, method='random', 
    extraInfo=expInfo, originPath=-1,
    trialList=data.importConditions('../Desktop/Countingpuppet/sounds_routine.xlsx', selection=choice(10, size = 4, replace = False)),
    seed=None, name='trials')
thisExp.addLoop(trials)  # add the loop to the experiment
thisTrial = trials.trialList[0]  # so we can initialise stimuli with some values
# abbreviate parameter names if possible (e.g. rgb = thisTrial.rgb)
if thisTrial != None:
    for paramName in thisTrial:
        exec('{} = thisTrial[paramName]'.format(paramName))

for thisTrial in trials:
    currentLoop = trials
    # abbreviate parameter names if possible (e.g. rgb = thisTrial.rgb)
    if thisTrial != None:
        for paramName in thisTrial:
            exec('{} = thisTrial[paramName]'.format(paramName))

    # ------Prepare to start Routine "trial"-------
    # update component parameters for each repeat
    sound1.setSound(Sounds, hamming=True)
    sound1.setVolume(1, log=False)
    # keep track of which components have finished
    trialComponents = [sound1, movie1]
    for thisComponent in trialComponents:
        thisComponent.tStart = None
        thisComponent.tStop = None
        thisComponent.tStartRefresh = None
        thisComponent.tStopRefresh = None
        if hasattr(thisComponent, 'status'):
            thisComponent.status = NOT_STARTED
    # reset timers
    t = 0
    _timeToFirstFrame = win.getFutureFlipTime(clock="now")
    trialClock.reset(-_timeToFirstFrame)  # t0 is time of first possible flip
    frameN = -1
    continueRoutine = True

    # -------Run Routine "trial"-------
    while continueRoutine:
        # get current time
        t = trialClock.getTime()
        tThisFlip = win.getFutureFlipTime(clock=trialClock)
        tThisFlipGlobal = win.getFutureFlipTime(clock=None)
        frameN = frameN + 1  # number of completed frames (so 0 is the first frame)
        # update/draw components on each frame
        # start/stop sound1
        if sound1.status == NOT_STARTED and tThisFlip >= 0.0-frameTolerance:
            # keep track of start time/frame for later
            sound1.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
            sound1.tStart = t  # local t and not account for scr refresh
            sound1.tStartRefresh = tThisFlipGlobal  # on global time
            sound1.play(when=win)  # sync with win flip

        # *movie1* updates
        if movie1.status == NOT_STARTED and tThisFlip >= 0.0-frameTolerance:
            # keep track of start time/frame for later
            movie1.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
            movie1.tStart = t  # local t and not account for scr refresh
            movie1.tStartRefresh = tThisFlipGlobal  # on global time
            win.timeOnFlip(movie1, 'tStartRefresh')  # time at next scr refresh
            movie1.setAutoDraw(True)

        # check for quit (typically the Esc key)
        if endExpNow or defaultKeyboard.getKeys(keyList=["escape"]):
            core.quit()

        # check if all components have finished
        if not continueRoutine:  # a component has requested a forced-end of Routine
            break
        continueRoutine = False  # will revert to True if at least one component still running
        for thisComponent in trialComponents:
            if hasattr(thisComponent, "status") and thisComponent.status != FINISHED:
                continueRoutine = True
                break  # at least one component has not yet finished

        # refresh the screen
        if continueRoutine:  # don't flip if this routine is over or we'll get a blank screen
            win.flip()

    # -------Ending Routine "trial"-------
    for thisComponent in trialComponents:
        if hasattr(thisComponent, "setAutoDraw"):
            thisComponent.setAutoDraw(False)
    sound1.stop()  # ensure sound has stopped at end of routine
    trials.addData('sound1.started', sound1.tStartRefresh)
    trials.addData('sound1.stopped', sound1.tStopRefresh)
    trials.addData('movie1.started', movie1.tStartRefresh)
    trials.addData('movie1.stopped', movie1.tStopRefresh)
    # the Routine "trial" was not non-slip safe, so reset the non-slip timer
    routineTimer.reset()
    thisExp.nextEntry()

# completed 1 repeats of 'trials'


# Flip one final time so any remaining win.callOnFlip() 
# and win.timeOnFlip() tasks get executed before quitting
win.flip()

# these shouldn't be strictly necessary (should auto-save)
thisExp.saveAsWideText(filename+'.csv')
thisExp.saveAsPickle(filename)
logging.flush()
# make sure everything is closed down
thisExp.abort()  # or data files will save again on exit
win.close()
core.quit()
```

The problem is that using np.choice only one number is reproduced and not the entire sequence of four randomly chosen numbers without repetitions. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this:

```
FPS = 60  # Frame rate of your monitor

from random import choice
from psychopy import visual, sound
win = visual.Window()
movie = visual.MovieStim(win, 'my_file.avi')
sounds = [sound.Sound('sound1.wav'), sound.Sound('sound2.wav'), sound.Sound('sound3.wav'), sound.Sound('sound4.wav')]

frame = 1
while movie.status != visual.FINISHED:
    movie.draw()  # Show the next frame of the movie
    if frame % FPS == 0:  # If a second has passed
        choice(sounds).play()  # Play a random sound
```